# Adding buildDir to Nuxt configuration breaks Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I've created a Nuxt app with "npx create-nuxt-app" command as stated in Nuxt documentation selecting Vuetify as one of the options. This creates a default Nuxt app which runs perfectly with Vuetify in webpack develop-mode. However when I add

`buildDir: './../functions/nuxt'`

to Nuxt configuration and run 'yarn dev' Vuetify becomes broken and render of the page stops whenever Vue reaches Vuetify and page goes blank.

These are main errors that browser gives

- [Vuetify] Multiple instances of Vue detected
- [Vue warn]: Error in beforeCreate hook: "Error: Vuetify is not properly initialized

Here is the nuxt.config.js

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  head: {
    title: 'Frame of Nuxt2 application on Firebase',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' }
    ]
  },
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  css: [
  ],
  plugins: [
  ],
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa'
  ],
  axios: {
  },
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  buildDir: './../functions/nuxt',
  build: {
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

It seems I lack understanding of how Vuetify works with Nuxt and can't think of possible reason why building app not in default way (by default it build it inside of project in `.nuxt` folder) breaks it.

Would really appreciate any insight

Answer (score 0):

Allrighty, it appears root folder of build destination must have a vuetify in node_modules. Adding dependency solves this. In my case for 'functions' directory.

`buildDir: './../functions/nuxt'`